# Function object properties

Tags: javascript

Every function object has `__proto__` as their internal property. They also have `prototype` property. Since `prototype` is also an object it has a `__proto__` property as well. My question is, do both the `__proto__` property inside the prototype and in the function object point to `Function.prototype`?

Comment: @Felix Kling haha i m relly weak in english .

Answer (score 1):

No. A function's prototype property (i.e. `SomeFunc.prototype`) is a normal object and so its internal `__proto__` property points to `Object.prototype`.

Simple way to test it:

```
function Foo() {};
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo) === Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype));
// logs false
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo) === Function.prototype);
// logs true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype) === Object.prototype);
// logs true
```

Only functions inherit from `Function.prototype`, no other objects.

Answer (score 1):

A function's attribute named `prototype` is a normal object which becomes the prototype for objects created when using that function as a constructor.

A function's actual prototype (accessible via `__proto__`) is an object called `Function.prototype`, which in order descends from `Object.prototype`.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: I've mspainted you a diagram.

Comment: +1 for the diagram. You might however add some other red arrows so we can see the "chains"

Answer (score 0):

No.

The hidden `__proto__` property, which shouldn't really be used directly by JS programmers is meant as the glue to tie an object to its prototype chain.

As such:

```
function x () {}

x.__proto__; // is a prototypical function, leading back to `Function.prototype`
```

However, `prototype` is just an object, which gets assigned to the `__proto__` property of whatever you're creating with `new`, inside the function.

As it's just a regular object, `__proto__` will eventually lead back to `Object.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

The `__proto__` property points to the `constructor` from the function when you use the `new` operator.

If your constructor is a instanceof `Function`, all the properties and methods in the `Function.proptotype` object will be accessible by the instance, and will use the same as context.

Some browsers don't implement access to `__proto__` object, so if you wan't to use, will lose compatibility.

More info in the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto